# Is this true: probability independent from i?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, expectation

We have a set of i.i.d. random variable $X_i$ with some discrete distribution.

Further we have a random variable Y, Independent from $X_i$ with a Binomial Distribution Bin(n,p).

Now we are interested in $$q_i := P[Y \geq X_i ]$$

Is it true that

$$q_i:=P[Y\geq X_i ] = \sum_{x} P[X_i =x] P[Y\geq x] =E_{X_i}[P[Y \geq X_i]].$$
Especially, $q_i$ is Independent from $i$ and for all $i$ we have that $q_i = q$ where $$q:=E_X[P[Y \geq X]]=\sum_{x} P[X=x] \sum_{j=x}^{n} { n \choose j} p^j (1-p)^{n-j}$$ where $X$ has the same Distribution as $X_i$.

Comment: Presumably $E[Y \ge X_i]$ means the expectation of an indicator which is $1$ when $Y \ge X_i$ and $0$ when $Y \lt X_i$

Comment: Aside from the notation, the most glaring issue here is that if the $X_i$s do not have totally discrete support, the summation is inappropriate.

Comment: So I have tried to fix the Notation (this with the indicator variable), but I am not sure. 

Aside from this: $X_i$ have discrete Support. Sorry for not mentioning that.. 

I try to fix all the mistakes and am very sorry for making them.

Comment: I know that I might have confused you with my Notation. But I tried really hard to fix it and would really appreciate even an easy "yes or no" answer. It is really important to me to know whether this is correct or not! Thank you!

Comment: It is true that $q_i$ does not depend on $i$ **under the condition that** $Y$ is independent of the family $(X_i)_i$, otherwise anything can happen. Then $q=E(F(Y))$, where $F:x\mapsto P(X\leqslant x)$ is the common CDF of the $X_i$s.

Comment: maybe I will introduce some Details to help you with my confusing Notation. 
I am interested only in the case that the $X_i$ are Independent from $Y$.

Comment: Thanks but details are irrelevant now, since the question is clear and my comment is a full answer.

Comment: Thank you for your help, Did! You got an upvote from me some minutes ago..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true that $q_i$ does not depend on $i$ *under the condition that $Y$ is independent of the family $(X_i)_i$* (otherwise anything can happen). Then $q=E(F(Y))$, where $F:x↦P(X⩽x)$ is the common CDF of the random variables $X_i$.

Comment: after accepting your answer, I saw that you work with the CDF, but in fact, I am not interested in $P(X\leq x)$ but in $P(X\geq x)$, but otherwise that is exactly what I wanted to hear. Or do I misunderstand something?